# Append to div but before any other button or submit element

Tags: jquery

I would like to insert this:

```
<input type="button" name="buttonback1" id="buttonback1" value="Back">
```

Before the buttons in this HTML:

```
<div id="formdiv">
.... whole load of textfields etc here ....

<input type="submit" name="formaction" value="save">
<input type="submit" name="formaction" value="send">
</div>
```

So I need to insert the back button to appear before the submit buttons. I tried using this:

```
$("#formdiv").append('<input type="button" name="buttonback1" id="buttonback1" value="Back">');
```

But it appends it to the end of the div after the submit buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.before()` method to append before an element

```
 $("#formdiv").find('input[value="save"]').before('<input type="button" name="buttonback1" id="buttonback1" value="Back">');
```

**EDIT**

if that button doesn't exist you can append it like this:

```
if($("#formdiv").find('input[value="save"]').length > 0){
   $("#formdiv").find('input[value="save"]').before('<input type="button" name="buttonback1" id="buttonback1" value="Back">');
}
else{
    $("#formdiv").append('<input type="button" name="buttonback1" id="buttonback1" value="Back">');
}
```

Comment: This works nicely. Is there anyway to have it also work if the save/submit buttons are not there? So it adds the back button anyway, but if the save/submit buttons do exist then it will insert before those first.

Comment: edit answer if tese button exist append before it else append at the end of the div @volumeone

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("#formdiv").find('input[type=submit]').first().before('<input ....">');
```

Comment: This works nicely. Is there anyway to have it also work if the save/submit buttons are not there? So it adds the back button anyway, but if the save/submit buttons do exist then it will insert before those first.

Comment: can check if `type=submit` has length, if so use this code, if not use the append you have

Comment: wonderful thank you so much. i used yours combined with the extra stuff from alessandro to make my solution. would like to vote both as answer but can't.